# QgsFeatureList features as QStrings

Tags: qgis, features, string

I am catching the selectionChanged signal and passing the selected layer to the registered method. Once here, I want to know the features that were selected. I do this with a call to layer.selectedFeatures().

The return type from this call is a QgsFeatureList. As a test, I'm trying to print the values of the features in the QgsFeatureList that was selected, or just display them in a simple way. I find that neither QgsFeatureList nor QgsFeature has any functions returning a QString.

How can I print the values of the features that were selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example from the Python Console:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
features = layer.selectedFeatures()
for feature in features:
    print feature['NAME']

Vancouver
Prince Rupert
Juneau
San Jose
Salt Lake City
Portland
```

Comment: Is there a way to extract all values from each feature without having to index them by name?

Comment: I could iterate using int indexes, but I was thinking more along the lines of one whole feature at a time.

Comment: Using the `QgsFeature.attributes()` function is what I was looking for. It returns all the attributes of a feature.